# C struct's attribute is null when expected to be a reference

Tags: c, linked-list, null, segmentation-fault

```
typedef struct node {
    char *string;
    struct node* next;  
} node;

typedef struct {
    node *head;  
    node *tail;
    node *curr;
} list;

list llInit(){
    list *linkedList = malloc(sizeof(list));
    linkedList->head = NULL;
    linkedList->tail = NULL;
    linkedList->curr = NULL;

    return *linkedList;
}

int llSize(list *myList){
    if (myList->head == NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    int size = 1;
    node *instance = myList->head;

    while(instance->next != NULL){
        instance = instance->next;
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}

int llAddToFront(list *myList,char *toStore){
    if (toStore == NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->string = toStore;

    newNode->next = myList->head;
    myList->head = newNode;

    if (myList->tail == NULL){
        myList->tail = newNode;
    }

    return 1;
}

int llAddToBack(list *myList, char *toStore){
    if (toStore == NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    if (myList->head == NULL){
        return llAddToFront(myList, toStore);
    }

    node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->string = toStore;

    newNode->next = myList->tail;
    myList->tail = newNode;

    return 1;
}

int main() {
    // add one element to front, size should be 1
    list two = llInit();
    llAddToFront(&two, "one");
    if (llSize(&two) != 1){
        printf("Test 2: Fail - size should be %d, was %d.\n", 1, llSize(&two));
    }

    if (one.head == NULL){
        printf("ERROR!!!!");
    }

    if (one.tail.string != "one"){
        printf("Test 2: Fail - unexpected tail string.\n");
    }
}
```

This is a linkedlist in C that stores strings.

For some reason, (in main) my head is null and prints the error message. I believe that I set it correctly in llAddToFront. Also, the if block after that creates a segmentation fault and I don't understand why.

Comment: In the posted code, you did not declare `one` anywhere!

Comment: wow. answer and i'll mark it.

Comment: @SDK4 Here's a better idea, rather than asking superfluous questions and expecting other people to do your debugging for you, why don't you learn how to produce an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The code does not compile. 
`test.c:84:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'one'
    if (one.head == NULL){
        ^
test.c:88:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'one'
    if (one.tail.string != "one"){
        ^
2 errors generated.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this compile? The list named one isn't declared and you're testing if its head is null.
I think you are running an old binary.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this:
`if (one.tail.string != "one")`

You should do this instead:
`if (strcmp(one.tail.string, "one"))`

Hope this helps